# Rounding a double to turn it into an int (java)

Tags: java, double, int, rounding

Right now I'm trying this:

```
int a = round(n);
```

where `n` is a `double` but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: You should really elaborate "not working" in more detail. What happens? What happens not? What did you expect? What errors did you got? Do you have a `round()` method in the same class? Did you `import static java.lang.Math.*`? Etc.. There are a lot of ways to round numbers and thus also a lot of possible answers. In other words, your question is vague and ambiguous and can't be reasonably answered in its current form. It's shooting in the dark.

Comment: Does "not working" mean not rounding to nearest int, or throwing exception, or not rounding up/down? This question is useless without having to cross-reference the context with the answer.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

What is the return type of the `round()` method in the snippet?

If this is the `Math.round()` method, it returns a Long when the input param is Double.

So, you will have to cast the return value:

```
int a = (int) Math.round(doubleVar);
```

Comment: Consider using Math.toIntExact(long) instead of just casting to an int; a double can hold quite a range of values and you probably don't want to silently throw out the most significant bits if your double is larger than you expect.

Comment: I believe the cast is not necessary. I'm not aware if it was in the past, but round does return int.

Comment: @Dropout Math.round returns an int if you give it a float, and a long if you give it a double.

Comment: This will overflow right?
        double bigValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        long result = (int) Math.round(bigValue);
result overflow to -1

Answer (score 30):

If you don't like Math.round() you can use this simple approach as well:

```
int a = (int) (doubleVar + 0.5);
```

Comment: There is clearly no valuable reason for not liking `Math.round()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6468757/1715716

Comment: This solution is shorter, does not need an import and is portable to many other programming languages with minimal changes. 

And it might even be faster depending on your platform: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091014/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-round-a-float-value-to-the-nearest-integer-in/12091343#12091343

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer, which I find **very useful** for the reason you mention. I was, by this comment, addressing people who would be afraid to use `Math.round()`, which does "literally" the same as the solution you provide, that is all. Cheers.

Comment: Yep, like nehz said, I believe this would round -2.1 to -1, for example.

Comment: This approach is incorrect. `Math.round(doublevar)` will perform rounding on the double number, basically returning the closest integer to the specified double. On the contrary, `(int) doublevar` will just remove the decimal portion of the double, potentially yielding a different result.
As an example, `Math.round(5.7)` will return 6, but `(int) 5.7` returns 5.

Comment: @AlbertoHormazabal, didn't you notice that he added `0.5`?

Comment: I wonder why during the last 6 years nobody wrote that this replacement for  `Math.round()` gives wrong results for negative input numbers. Ok here it is: Do not replace!

Answer (score 12):

Rounding ***double*** to the "nearest" ***integer*** like this:

**1.4** -> **1**

**1.6** -> **2**

**-2.1** -> **-2**

**-1.3** -> **-1**

**-1.5** -> **-2**

```
private int round(double d){
    double dAbs = Math.abs(d);
    int i = (int) dAbs;
    double result = dAbs - (double) i;
    if(result<0.5){
        return d<0 ? -i : i;            
    }else{
        return d<0 ? -(i+1) : i+1;          
    }
}
```

You can change condition **(result<0.5)** as you prefer.

Comment: I agree with the anivaler's answer. But if you need to just round off to highest integer number, you can you like below:

double decimalNumber = 4.56777;
System.out.println( new Float( Math.round(decimalNumber )) );

Output : 5

Answer (score 9):

The Math.round function is overloaded
When it receives a float value, it will give you an int. For example this would work.

```
int a=Math.round(1.7f);
```

When it receives a double value, it will give you a long, therefore you have to typecast it to int.

```
int a=(int)Math.round(1.7);
```

This is done to prevent loss of precision. Your double value is 64bit, but then your int variable can only store 32bit so it just converts it to long, which is 64bit but you can typecast it to 32bit as explained above.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.math.*;
public class TestRound11 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    double d = 3.1537;
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
    bd = bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    // output is 3.15
    System.out.println(d + " : " + round(d, 2));
    // output is 3.154
    System.out.println(d + " : " + round(d, 3));
  }

  public static double round(double d, int decimalPlace){
    // see the Javadoc about why we use a String in the constructor
    // http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d));
    bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int round(double d) {
    if (d > 0) {
        return (int) (d + 0.5);
    } else {
        return (int) (d - 0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives the wrong answer (1.0) for the largest double below 0.5 : `0.4999... + 0.5` rounds up to 1.0 in the default rounding mode, but the original input was below half-way so  it's not a tie-break situation, it should round down to 0.0 in every rounding mode except CEIL (or FLOOR for the equivalent -0.4999... input).  You might want to use code like this in some cases, but it's important to point out problems, and difference in tiebreak behaviour from Math.round.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of `Math.round` says:

> Returns the result of rounding the argument to an **integer**. The result
>   is equivalent to `(int) Math.floor(f+0.5)`.

No need to cast to `int`. Maybe it was changed from the past.

Comment: There are 2 Math.round methods. The one which takes a float returns an integer, that is correct. But the one that takes a double returns a long.

Answer (score -1):

You really need to post a more complete example, so we can see what you're trying to do. From what you have posted, here's what I can see. First, there is no built-in `round()` method. You need to either call `Math.round(n)`, or statically import `Math.round`, and then call it like you have.

Comment: There are no global functions in java, for a start.