# Converting double to integer in Java

Tags: java, casting, double, rounding

In Java, I want to convert a double to an integer, I know if you do this:

```
double x = 1.5;
int y = (int)x;
```

you get y=1. If you do this:

```
int y = (int)Math.round(x);
```

You'll likely get 2. However, I am wondering: since double representations of integers sometimes look like 1.9999999998 or something, is there a possibility that casting a double created via Math.round() will still result in a truncated down number, rather than the rounded number we are looking for (i.e.: 1 instead of 2 in the code as represented) ?

(and yes, I do mean it as such: Is there *any* value for x, where y will show a result that is a truncated rather than a rounded representation of x?)

If so: Is there a better way to make a double into a rounded int without running the risk of truncation?

---

Figured something: Math.round(x) returns a long, not a double. Hence: it is impossible for Math.round() to return a number looking like 3.9999998. Therefore, int(Math.round()) will never need to truncate anything and will always work.

Comment: Math.round(double) returns a long, not a double.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

> is there a possibility that casting a double created via `Math.round()` will still result in a truncated down number

No, `round()` will always round your double to the correct value, and then, it will be cast to an `long` which will truncate any decimal places.  But after rounding, there will not be any fractional parts remaining.

Here are the docs from [`Math.round(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)):

> Returns the closest long to the argument. The result is rounded to an integer by adding 1/2, taking the floor of the result, and casting the result to type long. In other words, the result is equal to the value of the expression:
>
> ```
> (long)Math.floor(a + 0.5d)
> ```

Comment: The important point is that the rounding is done within the round method. A long value is returned, which can safely be cast to an int (assuming returned value will always be within int range).

Comment: Yes. Can't imagine a /long/ to int giving problems. Obviously! Should've figured this :(

Comment: While it is true that truncation will not occur because of the rounding, you still may not get the expected results simply due to the casting from double which is a very large number `[max double: 1.7976931348623157E308]` to int which is much much smaller `[max int: 2147483647]`. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 46):

For the datatype `Double` to `int`, you can use the following:

```
Double double = 5.00;

int integer = double.intValue();
```

---

This truncates (floors), and does not round. Use at your own risk.

Comment: He is looking for a rounded value.

Comment: I don't think that will give what you expect for 4.99999999999 (will give 4 not 5)

Comment: Mine says "double cannot be dereferenced".

Comment: This truncates (floors), and does not round. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 23):

```
Double perValue = 96.57;
int roundVal= (int) Math.round(perValue);
```

Solved my purpose.

Comment: Very Good! Thanks! Worked!