# java receive incorrect BeanShell result

Tags: java, beanshell

I have very big numbers and complex string equations to solve in java. For that I use BeanShell. In this equations can also contain bitwise binary operations e.g.

```
 (log(100)*7-9) & (30/3-7)
```

should be 1.
As I said I need to handle huge numbers for that I add the `L` to each number which works fine so far. But here I have the problem when computing something like `3/2` I just receive `1` and not `1.5`. Then I've tried to add a `D` for double values to each number which gives me the `1.5` but here I receive an error on the binary operations `and or xor` etc. because of course they can only be applied to Integer values.

Is there a way to receive `double` values when needed and still perform the binary operations (of course only when I have integer values)?

Answer (score 0):

I would declare the operands as doubles at the outset. It seems to me leaving Beanshell to promote/demote based on the answer introduces uncertainty into your code.

You can cast the double to an int and perform the binary operation every time. As this is a narrowing primitive conversion you should familiar yourself with the [Java Language Specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

[(Another possibly helpful answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468730/converting-double-to-integer-in-java)

Comment: When I always cast the right and left site of the binary op to an int it will work, but I shouldn't because when I have something like `((5-2)/2) and ((3-2)/2) -> 1.5 and 0.5` I won't to receive an error without simply cutting of the decimal part... Is there probably an alternative to BeanShell for solving such equations?

Comment: Why not write a function that tells you it's an integer? Example: `isInt(i) { return Math.floor(i) == i; }`