# How do you round a number to the closest integer in java without using the "round function" or "if and else statements"?

Tags: java

I have to round a number to the nearest integer. So 4.3 would be rounded to 4 and 4.7 would be rounded to 5. Numbers that have decimals in the middle like 4.5 would be rounded to 5 as well. I have to do this rounding without using and "Math." functions or "if and else statements".

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Why can't you use Math.round?

Comment: Add 0.5 and truncate.  (Is this a trick question?)

Comment: Can't you just cast to an `int`?

Comment: @JoshM: what will casting 4.7 return?

Comment: 4, but casting by doing (int)(4.7+.5) will return 5.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ah, yes it returns 4. My bad :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. Add 0.5 to the number and then cast it to an int. Like this:

```
int rounded = (int) (unrounded + 0.5);
```

This works because if the decimal part is less than 0.5, the integer part stays the same, and truncation gives the right result. If the decimal part is more that 0.5, the integer part increments, and again truncation gives what we want.

Comment: While this is correct, it's not encouraging the OP to be self-learning.

Comment: This wont work for negative integers.

Comment: This gives the wrong answer (1.0) for the largest double below 0.5.  `0.4999... + 0.5` rounds up to `1.0` in the default rounding mode, but the original input was below half-way so should round down to 0.0 in every rounding mode except CEIL.  (I think it's correct for all other non-negative numbers).  You might want to use code like this in some cases, but it's important to point out problems, and differences from Math.round.

Comment: Also, `(int)double` truncates toward zero, so as Bikram points out, it's not even close to rounding to nearest for negative numbers.  e.g. `-1.75` becomes `(int)(-1.25)` which is `-1`.  Some answers on [Rounding a double to turn it into an int (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2654839) propose branching on `unrounded < 0`, but then just add or subtract `0.5` which has the same problem I mentioned in my previous comment for an input of `nextafter(0.5, -infinity)` (the double just below 0.5)