# Converting a variable from Double to Int

Tags: java, type-conversion

Lets say that I have variable tmp which is a double, and I want to convert tmp to an int, but still have the variable called tmp. How would I do this?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding a double to turn it into an int (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654839/rounding-a-double-to-turn-it-into-an-int-java)

Comment: This is a duplicate question to many others on this site, please google your questions or look them up on this site before posting a question

Comment: Why do you want to still have the variable called tmp? You'll have to assign this int value to another variable as `tmp` is declared as `double` and not `int`.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was any way to convert the type of a variable without using another variable. I have looked through the site and online, and have not found an answer to that question.

Comment: @user2336315 is correct, it would be best that you store your double into a different variable then declare tmp as an int and follow the links posted to figure out how to convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the same variable as both an `int` and a `double`.

You can have this though:

```
double d = 0.1d;
int i = (int) d;
d = (double) i;
System.out.println(d);
```

Basically you first cast your `double` to an `integer`, losing the fraction. Afterwards you cast it to a `double` again and assign it to your `d` variable. You don't have to explicitly do the casting from `int` to `double` because it is a widening conversion, but it makes it more clear what happens.

The end result is that your `d` variable now has a value that can be precisely interpreted by an integer but on the other hand you also, well, basically threw away your fraction. Your variable **did not** change its type, however.

You can write this less verbosely like this:

```
double d = (int) 0.1d;
```