# Bézier curve map x,y points to screen

Tags: java, math, interpolation, bezier

hi recently i implemented the bezier curve it works fine but my problem is i dont know how to map x,y points to the screen because it gives me x,y in form of decimal points i will appreciate any help 
this is my code which works i think       .

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class Bezier {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<Point> CP = new ArrayList<Point>();
            CP.add(new Point(-5, 0));
            CP.add(new Point(0, 5));
            CP.add(new Point(5, 0));
            CP.add(new Point(0,-5));


            Bezier curve = new Bezier(3, 0, 0.01, CP);
            curve.DefineBezierCurve();

            ArrayList<Point>Results = curve.getCurvePoints();

            for(int i = 0; i<Results.size() ; i++){
                Point x = Results.get(i);
                System.out.println(x.Y);
            }


        }
    //  class definitions
        private ArrayList<Point> controlPoints;// the control points
        private double t;//the value of t indicates the location of the point on the line sigment
        private double step;// the increment value that the t increments
        private int N;//the Beziar Curve Order
        private ArrayList<Point>CurvePoints;// genrated (x,y) values of the curve

    // constructor
        public Bezier(int n , double t , double step ,ArrayList<Point> CP ){
            this.N = n ;
            this.t = t;
            this.step = step;
            this.controlPoints = CP;
            CurvePoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
        }

        private int factorial(int x){
            int result =1;
            for(int i= x ; x>0 ; x--){
                result*=x;
            }
            return result;
        }
        private int BinomialCoefficient(int i){
            // we get the order form the global variable
            int factN = factorial(this.N);
            int factI = factorial(i);
            int factN_I = factorial(this.N-i);
            int theCoefficient = (factN/(factI*factN_I));
            return  theCoefficient ;
        }
        private Point BI_N_P(int i){
            int coefficient = BinomialCoefficient(i);
            Point CurrentControlPoint = this.controlPoints.get(i);
            double X = coefficient* Math.pow(t,i)* Math.pow((1-t),(this.N-i))*CurrentControlPoint.X ;
            double Y = coefficient* Math.pow(t,i)* Math.pow((1-t),(this.N-i))*CurrentControlPoint.Y ;
            Point Tmp  = new Point(X, Y);
            return Tmp;
    //      this.CurvePoints.add(PointOnCrve);
        }
        private void DefineBezierCurve(){
            while(t<=1){
                Point PointOnCurve = new Point(0, 0);
                for(int i = 0 ; i<=this.N ; i++){
                    Point tmp = BI_N_P(i);
                    PointOnCurve.X+=tmp.X;
                    PointOnCurve.Y+=tmp.Y;
                }
                this.CurvePoints.add(PointOnCurve);
                this.t+=this.step;
            }
        }

        public ArrayList<Point> getCurvePoints(){
            return this.CurvePoints;
        }

    }
    class Point{    
        public double X;
        public double Y;
        public Point(double x,double y){
            X=x;
            Y=y;
        }
    }
```

i used the genrated points to draw them in excel and this was my result 
[image]

example of cubic bezier curve  initial t=0,step = 0.01 , with control points 
(-5, 0),(0, 5),(5, 0),(0,-5)
generated X points

```
-5.0
-4.85001
-4.700079999999999
-4.55027
-4.400639999999999
-4.25125
-4.102159999999999
-3.9534299999999996
-3.80512
-3.6572900000000006
-3.5100000000000007
-3.3633100000000002
-3.2172800000000006
-3.07197
-2.92744
-2.7837499999999995
-2.6409599999999993
-2.4991299999999996
-2.3583199999999995
-2.2185899999999994
-2.0799999999999996
-1.9426099999999988
-1.8064799999999992
-1.6716699999999989
-1.5382399999999987
-1.4062499999999998
-1.2757599999999993
-1.1468299999999993
-1.0195199999999995
-0.8938899999999995
-0.7699999999999991
-0.6479099999999991
-0.527679999999999
-0.4093699999999989
-0.29303999999999886
-0.17874999999999885
-0.06655999999999862
0.043470000000001674
0.15128000000000164
0.256810000000002
0.3600000000000019
0.4607900000000018
0.5591200000000022
0.6549300000000019
0.7481600000000019
0.838750000000002
0.9266400000000021
1.011770000000002
1.094080000000002
1.173510000000002
1.2500000000000018
1.3234900000000016
1.3939200000000018
1.4612300000000018
1.5253600000000018
1.5862500000000017
1.6438400000000017
1.6980700000000017
1.7488800000000018
1.7962100000000016
1.8400000000000019
1.8801900000000014
1.916720000000001
1.9495300000000007
1.9785600000000012
2.0037500000000006
2.0250400000000006
2.042370000000001
2.05568
2.0649100000000002
2.0700000000000003
2.07089
2.06752
2.0598299999999994
2.0477599999999994
2.031249999999999
2.010239999999999
1.984669999999999
1.9544799999999984
1.9196099999999983
1.8799999999999981
1.8355899999999976
1.7863199999999972
1.7321299999999973
1.672959999999997
1.6087499999999963
1.539439999999996
1.4649699999999957
1.3852799999999954
1.3003099999999952
1.2099999999999946
1.1142899999999942
1.0131199999999938
0.9064299999999934
0.7941599999999929
0.6762499999999925
0.552639999999992
0.4232699999999916
0.28807999999999107
0.14700999999999054
```

generated Y points

```
0.0
0.14701
0.28808
0.42327
0.55264
0.6762500000000001
0.79416
0.90643
1.0131200000000002
1.1142900000000002
1.21
1.3003099999999999
1.3852799999999996
1.4649699999999997
1.5394399999999997
1.6087499999999997
1.6729599999999996
1.7321299999999997
1.78632
1.83559
1.88
1.91961
1.95448
1.98467
2.0102400000000005
2.0312500000000004
2.0477600000000002
2.0598300000000003
2.0675200000000005
2.0708900000000003
2.0700000000000003
2.0649100000000002
2.0556800000000006
2.0423700000000005
2.0250400000000006
2.00375
1.9785599999999997
1.9495300000000002
1.91672
1.8801899999999998
1.8399999999999999
1.7962099999999999
1.748879999999999
1.6980699999999993
1.6438399999999993
1.5862499999999993
1.5253599999999992
1.461229999999999
1.3939199999999987
1.3234899999999983
1.2499999999999982
1.173509999999998
1.094079999999998
1.011769999999998
0.9266399999999977
0.8387499999999977
0.7481599999999973
0.6549299999999975
0.5591199999999971
0.46078999999999715
0.359999999999997
0.2568099999999969
0.15127999999999653
0.043469999999996345
-0.06656000000000395
-0.17875000000000396
-0.2930400000000042
-0.40937000000000445
-0.5276800000000048
-0.6479100000000048
-0.7700000000000049
-0.8938900000000052
-1.0195200000000053
-1.1468300000000053
-1.2757600000000053
-1.4062500000000062
-1.538240000000006
-1.6716700000000062
-1.8064800000000063
-1.9426100000000066
-2.0800000000000067
-2.218590000000007
-2.3583200000000066
-2.499130000000007
-2.6409600000000077
-2.783750000000008
-2.927440000000008
-3.0719700000000083
-3.217280000000008
-3.363310000000008
-3.5100000000000087
-3.6572900000000086
-3.805120000000009
-3.9534300000000084
-4.102160000000009
-4.251250000000009
-4.40064000000001
-4.550270000000009
-4.7000800000000105
-4.85001000000001
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding a double to turn it into an int (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654839/rounding-a-double-to-turn-it-into-an-int-java)

Comment: does that seems like casting double to int problem -_- ??

Comment: *"it works fine but my problem is i dont know how to map x,y points to the screen **because it gives me x,y in form of decimal points**"*, so yes, indeed.

Comment: dude i know that but here you cannot simply cast it to an int there must be a way that when you do it the resultant curve is the same hope its clear now

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the set of points by some scale factor, then round to an integer. I would suggest the factor `Screen Width/MAX(list of x points)` for x, and `Screen Height/MAX(list of y points)` for y. This should give you a list of points scaled to the current size of the screen. Here's some python code that implements the idea.

```
X = "-5.0 -4.85001 -4.700079999999999 -4.55027 -4.400639999999999 -4.25125 -4.102159999999999 -3.9534299999999996 -3.80512 -3.6572900000000006 -3.5100000000000007 -3.3633100000000002 -3.2172800000000006 -3.07197 -2.92744 -2.7837499999999995 -2.6409599999999993 -2.4991299999999996 -2.3583199999999995 -2.2185899999999994 -2.0799999999999996 -1.9426099999999988 -1.8064799999999992 -1.6716699999999989 -1.5382399999999987 -1.4062499999999998 -1.2757599999999993 -1.1468299999999993 -1.0195199999999995 -0.8938899999999995 -0.7699999999999991 -0.6479099999999991 -0.527679999999999 -0.4093699999999989 -0.29303999999999886 -0.17874999999999885 -0.06655999999999862 0.043470000000001674 0.15128000000000164 0.256810000000002 0.3600000000000019 0.4607900000000018 0.5591200000000022 0.6549300000000019 0.7481600000000019 0.838750000000002 0.9266400000000021 1.011770000000002 1.094080000000002 1.173510000000002 1.2500000000000018 1.3234900000000016 1.3939200000000018 1.4612300000000018 1.5253600000000018 1.5862500000000017 1.6438400000000017 1.6980700000000017 1.7488800000000018 1.7962100000000016 1.8400000000000019 1.8801900000000014 1.916720000000001 1.9495300000000007 1.9785600000000012 2.0037500000000006 2.0250400000000006 2.042370000000001 2.05568 2.0649100000000002 2.0700000000000003 2.07089 2.06752 2.0598299999999994 2.0477599999999994 2.031249999999999 2.010239999999999 1.984669999999999 1.9544799999999984 1.9196099999999983 1.8799999999999981 1.8355899999999976 1.7863199999999972 1.7321299999999973 1.672959999999997 1.6087499999999963 1.539439999999996 1.4649699999999957 1.3852799999999954 1.3003099999999952 1.2099999999999946 1.1142899999999942 1.0131199999999938 0.9064299999999934 0.7941599999999929 0.6762499999999925 0.552639999999992 0.4232699999999916 0.28807999999999107 0.14700999999999054"
X = X.split(" ");
absX = list();
for x in X:
    absX.append(abs(float(x)));
max_X = max(absX);
min_X = min(X);
screen_width = 1024;
scale_factor = screen_width/float(max_X + float(max(X)));
newX = list();
for x in X:
    x = int(float(x)*scale_factor) + screen_width;
    newX.append(x)
print(newX);
```

This returns the following list of X coordinates:

```
[300, 322, 344, 366, 387, 409, 430, 452, 473, 495, 516, 537, 559, 580, 601, 621, 642, 663, 683, 703, 723, 743, 763, 782, 802, 821, 840, 858, 877, 895, 913, 931, 948, 965, 982, 999, 1015, 1030, 1045, 1061, 1076, 1090, 1104, 1118, 1132, 1145, 1158, 1170, 1182, 1193, 1205, 1215, 1225, 1235, 1244, 1253, 1262, 1269, 1277, 1284, 1290, 1296, 1301, 1306, 1310, 1314, 1317, 1319, 1321, 1323, 1323, 1323, 1323, 1322, 1320, 1318, 1315, 1311, 1307, 1301, 1296, 1289, 1282, 1274, 1266, 1256, 1246, 1236, 1224, 1212, 1199, 1185, 1170, 1155, 1139, 1121, 1104, 1085, 1065, 1045]
```

And here's the Y:

```
[768, 784, 799, 814, 829, 843, 856, 868, 880, 891, 902, 912, 921, 930, 938, 946, 953, 960, 966, 971, 976, 981, 984, 988, 991, 993, 995, 996, 997, 997, 997, 997, 996, 994, 992, 990, 987, 984, 980, 976, 972, 967, 962, 956, 950, 944, 937, 930, 922, 914, 906, 898, 889, 880, 870, 861, 851, 840, 830, 819, 807, 796, 784, 772, 761, 749, 736, 723, 710, 697, 683, 669, 655, 641, 627, 612, 598, 583, 568, 553, 538, 522, 507, 491, 475, 460, 444, 428, 411, 395, 379, 363, 346, 330, 313, 297, 280, 264, 247, 230]
```

This script isn't perfect and doesn't return values within the correct range, but it should give you an idea as of where to start.