# How do I round a float but keep it a float (i.e. without converting it to int)?

Tags: java, floating-point, simplify

for example i have a result of circle area = 4.3, my question is 'when i get number grater than .5 [for example(4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9)], i want it to give me 5.0, but if less than .5 [4.4, 4.3, 4.2, 4.1] then show me 4.0'

i tried `Math.round()` but it converts float to int like [4], but i don't want to convert it to int

is there a way to do this?

here is my code:

```
private float radius;
private double result;

public void show(float x)
{
    this.radius = x;
    this.result=Math.pow(x,2)*Math.PI;

    System.out.println("result is: "+result);
}
```

clearly, i want both method(Math.floor()) and (Math.ceil()) in one function
thanks

Comment: `Math.round(4.5f)` will return 5 and do exactly what you want. And converting an int to a float/double really isn't that hard at all.

Comment: Alternatively, since you know the area will always be positive, you could use `Math.floor( area + .5 )`.

Comment: `(float)Math.round(x)` makes the int again a float. However `float` and `double` are an approximation (of sums of powers of 2), without fixed number of decimals, and 5.3 has in reality a small error, 10000*5.3 will not be exactly 53000.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS thanks, =)

Comment: [Rounding a double to turn it into an int (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2654839)

Comment: @Thomas wow, this is exactly what i want! thank you very much

Comment: @Dukeling yes it works, but i don't want to convert float to int, i want to keep the float point, like(if the point >.5, floor it, and if the point <.5, ceil it) thanks

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks, it works =), but for ("10000*5.3") , I tried windows calculator and it gives me exactly 53000! i don't know if windows has it's own exception handler

Comment: The Windows calculator internally does not use float/double, but something like what is BigDecimal in java.

Comment: @Dukeling thanks :)

Comment: @JoopEggen it's strange to me, i mean i'm beginner of codding in java i absolutely have no idea about what you mean by ("windows calculator internally does not use float/double")(sorry for that) or maybe because my English is bad(i don't understand too much English) . sorry, thanks :)

Comment: To avoid be able to calculate more precise, with a precision after the decimal point, java has the class BigDecimal. There `12.01 * 4.0` is exactly `48.040`. (BTW only about 10% of the world are good English speakers, and the number is slowly diminishing.)

Comment: @JoopEggen thank you for your help, i think i'm understand

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.rint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint(double)) is probably closest to what you're looking for. Note that it [rounds half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).